# perl App::Cmd call subcommand from script

Tags: perl, command-line-arguments

I am trying to call a command line application implemented using `App::Cmd` from another script (without a system call).

My application is taken from the [tutorial](http://search.cpan.org/dist/App-Cmd/lib/App/Cmd/Tutorial.pod)  for the package, having a  a script `yourapp`:

```
#!/usr/bin/perl
use YourApp;
```

an application class `YourApp.pm`:

```
package YourApp;
use App::Cmd::Setup -app;
1;
```

and a command class `YourApp/Command/initialize.pm` with one option `myoption`:

```
package YourApp::Command::initialize;
use YourApp -command;

sub opt_spec {
    return ( [ "myoption|m=s",  "my option", ],);
}

sub execute {
    my ($self, $opt, $args) = @_;        
    my $mo = $opt->myoption;
    print "Options : $mo \n";
}

1;
```

Executing the subcommand from a script works fine, calling:

`./yourapp initialize --myoption aaa` prints the desired result `Options : aaa`.

Now I would like to invoke the `execute` subroutine from another perl script, but when I pass the option as a hash reference to `execute` as below:

```
my $opts = {m=>"aa"}; 
use YourApp::Command::initialize;
YourApp::Command::initialize->execute($opts);
```

perl complains `Can't call method "myoption" on unblessed reference`.
When calling `execute` via the command, `$opts` is blessed as `Getopt::Long::Descriptive::Opts::__OPT__::2`. However, blessing `$opts` in my script still causes an error.

Any hints how to call `execute` from a script?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because it is a command-line app it needs to interact with `@ARGV`. So if you manually set the options in `@ARGV` and call `YourApp->run`, it will read those options and App::Cmd will make the call to `execute()`.

```
use YourApp;
local @ARGV = qw( initialize --myoption aaa );
YourApp->run;
```

Comment: Yes, this works for me! I've seen that `App::Cmd::Tester` does it in a similar way. Why does ARGV to be declared `local` though?

Comment: oh, the `local` is not mandatory. I did that for a series of tests in my t scripts.